# Acumatica Field Appearing in Grid and Form but not in the Mobile App

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to add the Service Order Line Ref field (SODetID) to the Appointment Entry screen (FS300200). I am able to see the field in the grid and the form view. But I can't seem to make it show in the mobile app on my Android. I tried 2 different MSDL's, a simple and a more complex one, and neither seem to work. However, both add the field in the preview like I would expect. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as always! Here is the MSDL I tried:

Simple:

```
update screen FS300200 {
  update container "Details" {
    add field "SODetID" {
      placeBefore field "InventoryID"
    }
  }
}
```

More Complex:

```
update screen FS300200 {
  update container "Details" {
    add field "SODetID" {
      placeBefore field "InventoryID"
      displayName = "SO Line Ref"
      forceIsVisible = True
      selectorDisplayFormat = Key
      pickerType = Searchable
      selector {
        fieldsToShow = 5
        add field "SODetID" {
          listDisplayFormat = CaptionValue
        }
        add field "InventoryID" {
          listDisplayFormat = CaptionValue
        }
        add field "TranDesc" {
          listDisplayFormat = CaptionValue
        }
        add field "LineType" {
          listDisplayFormat = CaptionValue
        }
        add field "Status" {
          listDisplayFormat = CaptionValue
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

One quick note, I am using the CacheAttached event to display an extra column in the lookup as well as to make sure Visible = true.

```
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
    [PXCustomizeSelectorColumns(new[] {
        typeof(FSSODet.lineRef),
        typeof(FSSODet.inventoryID),
        typeof(FSSODet.tranDesc),
        typeof(FSSODet.lineType),
        typeof(FSSODet.status),
        typeof(FSSODet.lastModifiedDateTime),
    })]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Service Order Line Ref.", Visible = true)]
    protected void FSAppointmentDet_SODetID_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the DAC name for SODetId instead of the Web Service name of ServiceOrderLineRef. At least it was an easy fix!